# Handlebar each not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a problem with the Handlebar each. The data is coming in, but it is not displaying for some reason.

Here is the code for the table to display and the javascript to process the information and display the data.

```
<script id="audit-log-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each data}}
<tr>
    <td>{{updated_at}}</td>
    <td>{{before_name}}</td>
    <td>{{action_sub1_type}}</td>
    <td>{{action_sub2_type}}</td>
    <td>{{created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{location_name}}</td>
    <td>{{machine_model}}</td>
    <td>{{unique_identifier}}</td>
    <td class="cur">{{value_before}}</td>
    <td>{{after_name}}</td>
    <td class="cur">{{value_after}}</td>                        
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the JavasSript code:

```
var getReportData = function() {
    $("#audit-log-placeholder").empty();
    var bank_template = Handlebars.compile($('#audit-log-template').html());
    var bank_placeHolder = $("#audit-log-placeholder");

    $.each(data,function(index,element){

            // Generate the HTML for each post
            var html = bank_template(element);
            // Render the posts into the page
            bank_placeHolder.append(html);

    });
});  
}
```

Is there a reason why the data is not displaying at all?

Comment: your js code is bit confusing, add a variable in js which you are passing to handlebar, where is the `data` variable which you have used in handlebars

Comment: Isn't your script code get all removed for `$("#audit-log-placeholder").empty()` ?
I guess you should check if #audit-log-placeholder is still there after the empty() function is called.